# Calculating how much vertical space is used by existing elements?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a Header element which has various content that is determining its height rather than a set property. Is it possible to get that height using CSS only? I want that in order to know how much vertical space I have left on the page and size a video div accordingly.

If I had the dimension set manually I could just use `height: calc(100vh - headerHeight);`

sample:

```html
<header>
  <p>something</p>
</header>
<div>
</div>
```

```css
header {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}
div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh; /* This should adjust so it doesn't overflow-y.*/
}
```

Comment: I think if you use flexbox you can do it.

Comment: hmm. yeah make a wrapper for header and content and flex-grow the content part.

Comment: It can be an idea, and should work ;) So you don't need calc anymore

Comment: That duplicate is so cluttered with irrelevant, age-old answers, I'm voting to re-open.

Comment: @connexo we should then add more answers to the duplicate. As as side note, the duplicate contain answers using Flexbox and CSS grid so it's still relevant.

Comment: 2 answers, and no reaction whatsoever to those within more than 7 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a CSS grid. Defining grid-columns with the last column defined in the unit `fr` (fraction) makes it fill the remaining space.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

main {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  background-color: #f0f4f8;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Hi I'm the header</p>
</header>
<main>Main here</main>
```

A very similar answer to a very old question (kind of hard to find due to currently having only 8 upvotes): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908512/3744304

IE 11 also supports CSS grid in its older spec. Please look up the `-ms-`prefixed property names and add them to your CSS if you need support for such old browsers.

Comment: *kind of hard to find due to currently having only 8 upvotes* --> we should then vote it up to make it more visible. This is the main purpose of voting.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I did, but with hundreds of upvotes necessary to realistically make it visible, how do you find enough people that care?

Comment: We simply do our part of the job and we hope other will do the same. We cannot do more than this. By the way, we should also *force* people to scroll and to go until the bottom to see the new answers. *lazy* users looking at only the accepted answers aren't really welcome here (IMO)

Comment: @connexo Both answers are valid methods. However both require containing the layout in a flex / grid wrapper, which would confine some of the architecture of the layout latter on.

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox you can achieve that.

```css
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
}
.content {
  background:red;
  flex: 1; //fill the rest of the container
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <p>something</p>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both answers are valid methods. However both require containing the layout in a flex / grid wrapper, which would confine some of the architecture of the layout latter on.